# How to output Get-ADComputer PowerShell results to JSON format containing IP and a parent object (Eg: Windows Servers)?

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, zabbix

I did the following ps1 script:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' -and Enabled -eq 'True'" | Select-Object Name, DNSHostName | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\adServers.json"
```

The output is:

```
[
    {
        "Name":  "exampleServer1",
        "DNSHostName":  "exampleServer1.domain.com"
    },
    {
        "Name":  "exampleServer2",
        "DNSHostName":  "exampleServer2.domain.com"
    } ]
```

It generates a list with all the objects that are described as "Windows Servers".
But what i want to achieve is:

> I will do more of this, but instead of Windows Servers i will also include lists with Linux Servers, and some other devices.
>
> I also need that one object contains the value IP Address. (Name, DNSHostName, IP Address)
>
> Since i will gather multiple devices with different descriptions, i need a title for each list i generate. Below a example for easier understanding...

Here's what i want to achieve, the output would be on the following JSON format:

```
{
    "Linux Servers": [{
            "Name": "exampleServer3",
            "DNSHostName": "exampleServer3.domain.com",
            "IP": "192.168.1.3"
        },
        {
            "Name": "exampleServer3",
            "DNSHostName": "exampleServer3.domain.com",
            "IP": "192.168.1.3"
        }
    ],
    "Windows Servers": [{
            "Name": "exampleServer1",
            "DNSHostName": "exampleServer1.domain.com",
            "IP": "192.168.1.1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "exampleServer2",
            "DNSHostName": "exampleServer2.domain.com",
            "IP": "192.168.1.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone knows how can i improve my code in order to do that?
I'm working on this because i will use it as a Discovery Rule for Zabbix Monitoring Software.

I don't really know on how or where to start.
Any tips or suggestion is really appreciate it...

PS: I will keep updating this answer with the codes i come up with, and all the tests i do.

Thanks in advance...

Edit:

I was able to solve this by using mklement0' and Mathias' excelent explanation for grouping the objects using Group-Object.

Final result:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$listaServidores = [ordered] @{}

# Raw command:
# Get-ADComputer -Filter "(OperatingSystem -Like '*' -and Enabled -eq 'True')" -Property OperatingSystem, IPv4Address | 
# Select-Object Name, DNSHostName, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem |

# Exportar para JSON: ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 "C:\adServers.json"
Get-ADComputer -Filter "(OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' -and Enabled -eq 'True')" -Property OperatingSystem, IPv4Address | 
Select-Object Name, DNSHostName, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem |
Group-Object {
    switch -Wildcard ($_.OperatingSystem) {
        '*Windows Server*'  { 'Windows Servers' }
        '*Windows 7*'   { 'Outdated Computers' } # I will use this later. Outdated users, need to update to Windows 10
        Default             { 'Others' } # Other devices Discovery Rules. Will dig around later
    }
} | 
ForEach-Object {
    $listaServidores[$_.Name] = 
        @($_.Group | Select-Object Name, DNSHostName, @{ Name='IP'; Expression='IPv4Address'})
}

$listaServidores | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 # !! -Depth is needed to avoid truncation
    # Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 "C:\adServers.json"
```

Comment: If those properties aren't already in AD, then you're really asking for a script to be written by us.

Comment: Not really, i'm asking on how could i do that. Not "Do for me". I really have no idea on the approach i would use for this! A documentation, a tool, a cmdlet would be very useful so i can at least know where to start!

Comment: Doesn't have to be directly said, to be implied. If you want other Operating Systems to be listed, you would have to get rid of your filter for just Windows Servers. If you want to select more properties, besides providing the property names using `-Properties`, you would have to select them as well. If they're in AD already. Otherwise, you would have to run a query against those machines to get the other info such as the IP.

Comment: Are you looking for just servers? Can you confirm the IP Address is a property in AD? If it is, you can try: `Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -Like '*Server*' -and Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties DNSHostName, IPAddress | Select-Object Name, DNSHostName, IPAddress`. If not, `Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -Like '*Server*' -and Enabled -eq 'True'" -Properties DNSHostName| Select-Object Name, DNSHostName, @{N='IPAddress';E={(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Name -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString} }` something like this should work.

Comment: At the moment, yes... Only Windows Servers. Unfortunately there isnt a property that contains the server IP Address. The only thing i could think of at the moment was doing a ping and storing the value on a variable, for using it alongside the json output...

Comment: do my 2nd suggestion with one of the posted answers. It will give you the IP, if it's online.

Comment: I was actually wrong about the properties... This command does contain a property that shows IP Address, which saves us a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet to group computers by their `.OperatingSystem` property, which allows you to construct an ordered hashtable<sup>[1]</sup> that translates into the desired JSON structure when passed to [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Initialize an ordered hashtable that will collect the groups.
$orderedHash = [ordered] @{}

Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Property DNSHostName, IPv4Address, OperatingSystem | 
  Group-Object OperatingSystem | # See below re higher-level grouping.
  ForEach-Object {
    # Add an entry named for the current group (OS)
    # with the array of the group's members as the value.
    $orderedHash[$_.Name] = 
      @($_.Group | Select-Object Name, DNSHostName, @{ Name='IP'; Expression='IPv4Address'})
  }

# Convert to JSON and save to a file.
$orderedHash | 
  ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 | # !! -Depth is needed to avoid truncation
    Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 C:\adServers.json
```

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71397683/45375) shows how to create groups *explicitly*, based on individually filtered `Get-ADComputer` calls, which allows arbitrary, higher-level groupings, as well as limiting processing to only computers of interest.

If processing *all* (enabled) computers is desired, you can achieve **higher-level grouping** with a tweak to the above solution too, by passing a *script block* (`{ ... }`) that performs the mapping as the (positionally implied) `-Property` argument.

E.g., instead of `Group-Object OperatingSystem`, you could to the following:

```
Group-Object {
  switch -Wildcard ($_.OperatingSystem) {
    '*Windows*' { 'Windows Servers' }
    '*Linux*'   { 'Linux Servers' }
    Default     { 'Others' } 
  }
}
```

---

<sup>[1] 
An *ordered* hashtable (`[ordered] @{ ... }`) - unlike a regular hashtable  (`@{ ... }`) - preserves the definition order of its entries.

`[ordered]` is the only qualifier supported, and while it looks like a cast to a (nonexistent) `[ordered]` type, it isn't; instead, it is syntactic sugar that that translates into a [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) instance (vs. [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) for a regular hashtable).

See the conceptual [about_Hash_Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) help topic.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[mklement0's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71397558/712649) shows you how to automatically group the computers by the `OperatingSystem` property and construct the resulting JSON based on those.

But what if you want a *different* label for each group, or you want some of them grouped together?

If you know how you want to label them up front, you can organize each group into a hashtable and associate the query filter you want to use for each:

```
$OSGroups = @{
  'LinuxServers' = "OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' -and Enabled -eq 'True'"
  'WindowsServers' = "OperatingSystem -Like '*Windows Server*' -and Enabled -eq 'True'"
}
```

Now we just need to use each of those entries to fetch the relevant computers and add them to a property named for the key (eg. `WindowsServers`) on an output object:

```
# prepare another hashtable to hold all the information
$outputData = [ordered]@{}

# loop throw the different groups of computers you want to report on
foreach($kvp in $OSGroups.GetEnumerator())
{
  $groupName = $kvp.Key
  $groupFilter = $kvp.Value

  # Assign the output for the given filter to the appropriate entry in our output dictionary
  $outputData[$kvp.Key] = Get-ADComputer -Filter $kvp.Value -and Enabled -eq 'True'" | Select-Object Name, DNSHostName
}

# this will now produce the desired output format
$outputData |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 |Set-Content path\to\out.json
```

Comment: Lovely. Thanks a lot, i was able to get useful information for both answer and come up with a perfect code that does exactly what i need! Thanks a lot, if i could i would mark the two answers as a best answer. Thanks again, Mathias!